# A sequence of positive integers $(a_n)$ contains each positive integer exactly once. Assume that...

Tags: real-analysis

> A sequence of positive integers $(a_n)$ contains each positive integer
> exactly once. Assume that if $m\neq n$ then $$\frac{1}{1998}<\frac{|a_m-a_n|}{|m-n|}<1998.$$ Prove that $|a_n-n|<2000000$ for all $n$.

Please give a hint for this problem. Just one hint will be appreciated.

Comment: An interesting problem.

Comment: I don’t think the close vote is warranted. I agree it would be nice if the OP had some direction, but sometimes even the best of us are left clueless. The OP isn’t attempting to misuse the site. The community seems to consider this an interesting post that is worth advancing. I think to close it would be an injustice.

Comment: A proof can be found on AoPS. However I don't see how it can be condensed into a hint.

Comment: @player3236, can you give me a link

Comment: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1998%7D%3C%5Cfrac%7B%7Ca_m-a_n%7C%7D%7B%7Cm-n%7C%7D%3C1998%24&p=1

Comment: @player3236, thanks for the link

Comment: This question is here, has been downvoted and has no answers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717236/how-to-prove-this-problem-about-sequences @gen-ℤreadytoperish

Comment: Why can't we say $a_1=2000001$ so that $a_1-1=2000000$

Comment: @Raffaele The difference is subtle but critical. The post you’ve linked simply says “How to do this problem?” whereas this post is asking for a hint.